# Broken Python installation on CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, python

I already searched for solution to my problem via Google and serverfault's search facility, but haven't found anything related specifically to my case.

Here's the problem: I needed python 2.7.3 on CentOS 5.8 machine which has only python 2.4.3 preinstalled. Also neither there's the suitable version in it's repositories nor I can upgrade installed version. That's why I decided to build python from source code. But I've made a mistake: instead of `make altinstall` I did `make install` thus changing default version of the current installation. It was before I found this article - [How to install Python 2.7.3 on CentOS 6.2](http://toomuchdata.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-python-2-7-3-on-centos-6-2/) . I guess 5.8 and 6.2 versions aren't different to the extent this article is inapplicable. After installation of new python version I installed pip, but once I tried to invoke it, I got "No module named pkg_resources" error. In order to solve this issue I installed setuptools from repository. But it had only led to another error: "Distribution Not Found". My final step was to follow the guide I posted the link to, but I was unable to perform last step: `easy_install-2.7 virtualenv` command threw "-bash: /usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7: .: bad interpreter: Permission denied" error. Now when I try to invoke `pip` or `pip-2.7` both commands raise the same error with different names of binaries after "-bash:".

Is there any way to fix this problem, so I could install new python version (2.7.3) alongside with the preinstalled one (2.4.3) according to the guide? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.: yum is working fine, although it needs python to function, so I hope the damage I unknowingly caused isn't very severe. Also I'm not a native English speaker, so I apologize for possible occasional grammatical and/or spelling errors.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try going back to the directory you ran the initial make install and attempt a:
`make uninstall`.

If that doesn't work you are going to need to remove it manually. You can figure out what path it took by looking at the make file or by: `make -n install > logfile 2>&1` Then you need to find the python package: `rpm -qa | grep python` and remove it `rpm -e -nodeps <package>`. To re-install it: `rpm -ivh --force <package>`.

Of course this is probably more work than just re-installing the OS, not easy, and not guaranteed to work...